# cant use linq "Last()" method

Tags: c#, linq

I dont know a whole lot about C# but I have this project I am working on where I would like to do something like this:

```
SortedDictionary<int, List<ChessMove>> possibleMovesByRank = new SortedDictionary<int, List<ChessMove>>();
...
var best = possibleMovesByRank.Keys.Last();
```

From what I have been able to find, this should use linq to return the key that has the highest value, however VS is giving me an error:

```
SortedDictionary.KeyCollection does not contain a definition for 'Last' and no extension method for 'Last'
```

Am I missing something or is my project not set up correctly or something?

Comment: Do you have `using System.Linq` in your class?

Comment: Read the rest of that error message.

Comment: ReSharper `ALT+ENTER` hehe

Comment: Remember that context is important. Try and make connections between syntax and the result. Consider why it worked in one class but not another. This is an important step in developing an efficient mental model.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 6):

Most likely, you are missing the [System.Linq](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.aspx) namespace in your C# file. This is an [Extension Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx) and [Enumerable.Last](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb358775.aspx) will not exist unless you include the relevant namespace.

Comment: Indeed paqogomez. Indeed. :)

Comment: @paqogomez - Well I hope people don't get too discouraged during the low rep phase. I'd hate to see competent people get fed up.

Comment: @ChaosPandion I concur.  I can attest that it is very difficult to get points these days.